# Static network configuration of Ubuntu 18.04 with cloud-init through Terraform

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, terraform, ubuntu-18.04, cloud-init

I am deploying Ubuntu 18.04 VMs on VMware vSphere using Terraform, and I need to apply some basic configurations so I'm using cloud-init.

Most of the things are working correctly (setting the hostname, adding users, running commands) but I'm totally failing to configure a static IP address to network interfaces.

I am using Ubuntu's [stock cloud images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/) deployed from their `.ova` files and immediately converted to templates without ever powering them on. I can see my data gets correctly rendered to a multi-part file in `/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt.i`, but then the network configuration does *not* get applied.

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong, I don't even know if the problem lies in the data location (multipart file name and content-type) or in its contents. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my cloud-init related code in Terraform:

```
data "template_file" "cloud-config" {
  template = <<YAML
#cloud-config
hostname: ${var.vm_hostname}
# Adds a user called 'example' with the password hash of 'passwort', sudo rights and the default ubuntu groups
users:
  - name: example
    passwd: $6$rounds=4096$P0uvlB9.8nsiY67$uuOxYSk6n/74Ds3JtV1mT6xYjOguwTWgNmOeHvcHiQa9zan57l8dvfHE/zlu19fDmJGySNzLmh6K0R2I1AU9o0
    lock_passwd: false 
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) ALL
    groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, floppy, video, plugdev, dip, netdev]
runcmd:
  - echo 'This instance was provisioned by Terraform.' >> /etc/motd
  - sed -i s/^PasswordAuthentication\ no\$/PasswordAuthentication\ yes/ /etc/ssh/sshd_config
power_state:
  mode: 'reboot'
  message: 'reboot triggered by cloud-init'
YAML
}

# network-config
data "template_file" "network-config-v2" {
  template = <<YAML
version: 2
ethernets:
  ens192:
    addresses: [${var.vm_ip4address}/${var.vm_ip4subnet}]
    gateway4: ${var.vm_ip4gateway}
YAML
}

data template_cloudinit_config "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true
  part {
    filename     = "init.cfg"
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = "${data.template_file.cloud-config.rendered}"
  }
  part {
    filename     = "network-config"
    # also tried text/plain here
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = "${data.template_file.network-config-v2.rendered}"
  }
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  # some details omitted for brevity
  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
    adapter_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]}"
  }
  wait_for_guest_net_routable = false
  vapp {
    properties {
      user-data = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered}"
    }
  }
}
```

These are the only relevant `cloud-init.log` lines I could find, which just say it is falling back to default dhcp configuration:

```
2019-04-26 13:04:14,373 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: no work necessary for renaming of [['00:50:56:86:ca:38', 'ens192', 'vmxnet3', '0x07b0']]
2019-04-26 13:04:14,375 - stages.py[INFO]: Applying network configuration from fallback bringup=False: {'config': [{'type': 'physical', 'name': 'ens192', 'mac_address': '00:50:56:86:ca:38', 'subnets': [{'type': 'dhcp'}]}], 'version': 1}
2019-04-26 13:04:14,397 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Selected renderer 'netplan' from priority list: None
2019-04-26 13:04:14,405 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml - wb: [644] 477 bytes
```

For what it's worth, I also tried using [network config format 1](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v1.html) without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so i had the same problem today, and i want to share the solution here.

The problem is that the user-data, that you are using via vsphere for the ubuntu cloud image cant change the network stuff! So you need to do things manually.

This was already spotted here, and *dalo* presented a nice, smart answer that really helped me out, and should fix your problem too:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2872244#2872244

So basically you override the default network config by cloud-init with your own and activate it afterwards. But be aware that the vm is getting a ip via dhcp on first boot,. After your netplan apply command was executed the vm gets the static ip and that persists across restarts.